# How to limit the number of ads per session?

Tags: java, android, admob

I have an app that displays an interstitial after a certain number of actions on a few pages of my app.  I am afraid that a user may wander around my app and have a whole bunch of interstitials smacked in their face.

How would I be able to limit the number of ads per session?  Like, a limit of 2 or 3 interstitials per session.

Googling this question yielded me this only relevant result:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/QZV3Z5Vy4pg

*"As for how you could do that, you could have a counter stored in shared preferences for example, and increment it every time you show an interstitial ad. If you get to 5, you could stop requesting interstitial ads for a while. The counter can be cleared when the app starts up again."*

I am very new at java code/development, and have done much research on SharedPreferences, but I am at a loss at how I can incorporate it into my code.

If anyone can help get me on the right path or have better ideas, I'm all ears!

Thank you!

EDIT: My code:

```js
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.xxxx.xxxxx.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class menuclass extends Activity{

 private InterstitialAd interstitial;
  
  // setting up counter for the interstitial ad
 private int counter = 0;
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      
              //Layout
  setContentView(R.layout.menulayout);
  
  
  //Prepare the Interstitial Ad
  interstitial = new InterstitialAd(menuclass.this);

  //Insert the Ad Unit ID
  interstitial.setAdUnitId("xxxxxx/xxxxxx");

  //Locate the Banner Ad in xml
  AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

  //Request for Ads
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

  //Add a test device to show Test Ads
  .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
  .addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxx")
  .build ();

  //Load ads into Banner Ads
  adView.loadAd(adRequest);

  //Load ads into Interstitial Ads
  loadInterstitial();
 
  //setting up buttons
    Button cp1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu1);
    Button cp2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu2);
    Button cp3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu3);
    Button cp4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu4);
    Button cp5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu5);
    
    
  // On Click Listeners, all buttons are involved in adding to the counter
    
    cp1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      startActivity(new Intent(menuclass.this, menu1class.class));
      
      counter++;
      displayInterstitial();
      
     }
    });
    
    cp2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      startActivity(new Intent(menuclass.this, menu2class.class));
      
      counter++;
      displayInterstitial();
     }
    });
    cp3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      startActivity(new Intent(menuclass.this, menu3class.class));
      
      counter++;
      displayInterstitial();
     }
    });
    cp4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      startActivity(new Intent(Cmenuclass.this, menu4class.class));
      
      counter++;
      displayInterstitial();
     }
    });
    cp5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      startActivity(new Intent(menuclass.this, menu5class.class));
      
      counter++;
      displayInterstitial();
     }
    });
  
 }


// displaying the interstitial
private void displayInterstitial()
{

//sharedpreferences
//Here, SharedPreference is changed to SharedPreferences
  SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("preference name", MODE_PRIVATE);
  //I will try 1 ad per session
  if(sp.getInt("key", 0) < 1){
     Editor ed = sp.edit();
     ed.putInt("key",(sp.getInt("key", 0) +1));
//Here, ed.commint(): is changed to ed.commit();
     ed.commit();
     //do adds work
   }
//end shared preferences

// If Ads are loaded and counter >= 5 show Interstitial, else show nothing.
if (interstitial.isLoaded() & counter>=5)
{
//Resets the counter
// counter = 0; (don't want counter at this point)
interstitial.show();
loadInterstitial();
}
}

private void loadInterstitial()
{
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().
addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
.addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
.build(); 
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
}

}
```

Comment: The IDE you're using has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 0):

**first of all call this** `loadInterstitial();` **in your oncreate to initally load your add**

**and also my example logic goes with the fact that if your button has been clicked alt least 5 times or less than 6** you can change it in the if statement..

i got rid of the first approach..

using sharepreference approach

```
  SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("preference name", MODE_PRIVATE);
  if(sp.getInt("key", 0) < any number here){
     Editor ed = sp.edit();
     ed.putInt("key",(sp.getInt("key", 0) +1));
     ed.commit();
     //do adds work
   }
```

call them when you need to show, probably put in a method

**EDIT 2** Bringing your code in play

Sir, your code is excellent just modify it this way

```
private void displayInterstitial(){

//sharedpreferences
//Here, SharedPreference is changed to SharedPreferences - thanks for changing it
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("preference name", MODE_PRIVATE);
//I will try 1 ad per session - when you call show(), it shows one add, okay? so
if(sp.getInt("key", 0) < 5){ // the zero is the default value if it's empty, the if statement checks if your sp integer is less than 5.
    // and continues if it checks true, if not, skip the whole statement, that's the logic here
   Editor ed = sp.edit(); 
   ed.putInt("key",sp.getInt("key", 0) +1);
   //Here, ed.commint(): is changed to ed.commit(); -thanks once more- i looked stupid at first
   ed.commit();
   //do adds work - you should put your add code in this method below "do adds work"
   if (interstitial.isLoaded() && counter < 5){ // that's your counter, the && checks if your first argument is true before it moves on to the 
  //second argument.. if it checks false, all is false & checks 
  // checks both arguments regardless of their outcome
        interstitial.show(); 
        loadInterstitial(); 
   } 
 }
  //end shared preferences, end of if-statement, end of logic code
} // end of method
```

the if statement is the checker, if the if statement checks false no add will show and it will always check true as long as your int is less than 5

**A**lso Sir, creating getters and setters is easy, getters and setters are just some function to help set and retrieve a variable/an object and you can create one by declaring your variable/object, and after that, on your eclipse go to **Source** then **generate getters and setters** .. they will generated by eclipse -(that's if you use eclipse-but similar to other ides)  it is very easy, also note that your initial way was excellent just need a little changes

*log lines in your code to know what is happening*

**AND THAT SHOULD WORK. SIR TOM**

Comment: Ok!  I feel like the sharedpreference approach is probably the most easiest for me at this point (since I'm not too sure how to create getters and setters).

When I tossed the code in, it wanted me to change "SharedPreference" to "SharedPreferences", it also wanted me to change "ed.commint();" to "ed.commit();", so I'm hoping that is correct.

Hopefully I understood this properly, but I've been trying to add this into one of my methods, but I don't have any luck.  Am I going about this the wrong way? 

I've tossed my simple code into my original post if you were curious.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, Sir, you are right, i wrote it off head, and i made a little mistakes, thanks for correcting i will change that in my code, and no, it is the right way, i will look at your code very soon, thanks for alerting me..Sir, @Tom

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  I used your code but unfortunately I was running into a bit of trouble.  At the top of my code, I used "private int counter = 0;" which I use to count all of my button presses.  So I tried changing the code line from "if (interstitial.isLoaded())" to "if (interstitial.isLoaded() **& counter>=5**)".  But, however, that didn't work well either (no interstitials would pop up).  Do you know how I can incorporate the counter into the new code properly?  Thanks again for the help, it is appreciated!

Comment: also i am very sorry i made a little error..check my answer@Tom

Comment: @Tom you can add your code this time `if (interstitial.isLoaded() & counter>=5)`, but note that you should change it to this way `if (interstitial.isLoaded() & counter<=5)` i was testing on if it is less not greater than so if you want to use greater than then change then other other to greater than, im referring to the if statement with the sharedpreference

Comment: hmmm.... this is very perplexing.  I took your "edit 2" code and tossed it into my new code and interstitials are still not popping up.  I tried changing the counters from `& counter>=5` to `& counter<=5` but no luck, no interstitial would pop up.  When I put my old `private void loadInterstitial()` method back in (without the sharedpreference) the interstitial _does_ pop up every 5 button clicks, so the actual interstitial isn't the issue.  I'm trying to think what could be the problem here, very strange

Comment: Also I really appreciate the help you have given me, it definitely means a lot!  I also like your notes, very useful stuff!

Comment: ok Sir, @Tom , but lastly copy, check the edit one more time, and copy the code.. because to be honest i do not know why it doesnt work because it should work this is not some head scratching problem.. maybe your add wasnt loaded..check logcat to know if your adds are loaded, ok?.. i added `&&`..happy coding

Comment: Unfortunately, my logcat tells me that this interstitial ad is neither loading nor failing to load (it's not being recognized).  My regular ads are being recognized like normal; but the logcat is reading the app activity as if this interstitial ad was not involved in the code at all.  Thank you